# opencv in python: Is there a easy way to compute the curvature of a contour?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I know that you can easily compute the center of mass, and area of a contour using the moment of the contours. Is there a quick way to compute the curvature of a contour with opencv in python?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In OpenCV,

> [a contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary points of
>   the object](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0).

A method for computing the curvature is described for example in:

[Driscoll MK, McCann C, Kopace R, Homan T, Fourkas JT, et al. (2012) "Cell Shape Dynamics: From Waves to Migration." *PLoS Comput Biol* 8(3): e1002392.
doi:10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002392](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3305346/pdf/pcbi.1002392.pdf)

They have a contour composed by 400 points (they call them *boundary points*) and:

> At each boundary point, we calculate the boundary curvature by fitting
>   a circle to that boundary point and the two points that are 10
>   boundary points away from it. The magnitude of the boundary curvature
>   is then defined as the reciprocal of the radius of that circle.

See also [this video from the above paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cell-Shape-Dynamics-From-Waves-to-Migration-pcbi.1002392.s007.ogv).

I am not familiar with Python and so I cannot suggest you a function for circle interpolation; anyway in order to fit a circle to three points you can follow the formulae from (25) to (34) from [Weisstein, Eric W. "Circle." From *MathWorld*--A Wolfram Web Resource](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle.html).

Taken from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1215914/10799

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28058/calculating-curvature-from-height-contours

Comment: @gansub I am sorry but I do not understand your question at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: almost identical question to this one - i have heights, i need contours and then curvatures.

Comment: @gansub it seems to me your problem is not to compute the curvature but to convert a point (x,y) to and from your "raster"?

Answer (score 0):

From this video https://youtu.be/4J30jzc3DD8 I made this python code:

```
# Circle fit
# number of points
N = 35 
# genreate list of angle in rad
t = np.linspace(0,np.pi,N)
# generate list of radius with noise
r = np.random.normal(loc=3,scale=0.2,size=N)
# generate list of circle points, with center +3,-2
x, y = r*np.cos(t) + 3, r*np.sin(t) - 2
# plot this circle
plt.plot( x, y )
# Make Matrix A
A=np.c_[-2*x,-2*y,np.ones_like(x)]
# Linear regression to solve best fitting
x0, y0, b = np.linalg.solve( A.T @ A, A.T @ (-(x**2)-(y**2)))
# Retrieve radius from b
r = np.sqrt( x0**2 + y0**2 - b )
# Draw result
plt.plot( r*np.cos(t) + x0, r*np.sin(t) + y0)
# display result parameters
print(f"x0={x0},y0={y0},r={r}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `convexityDefects` function described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects). for python usage see this [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html).

Comment: To compute convexity defects, I guess we need a binary image with a point set having intensity 1 and others 0. The convexity defects would relate to this point set (like the star shape shown in the tutorial link you've shared). However, is it possible to find curvature at every point in a given image using first and second order derivatives at those points?